SupabaseJS join without including join table as a property in the response
const { data, error } = await this.client
      .from('tableA')
      .select('*, tableB!inner(tableC!inner())')
      .eq('tableAPK', pk)
      .eq('tableB.tableC.id', tableCPK)
      .returns<TableAObject[]>();

This code returns TableAObject array with tableB: {} property within each object. As in,
{ ...tableAProperties, tableB: {} }. However, I would like for it to not be there. I joined purely for filtering reasons. Any help is appreciated.
